# Magento 2.3: How to configure magento CLI commands to use custom names for dangerous redis commands

Tags: magento2, cache, security, cli, redis

## Environment

> ***OS:*** Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
>
> ***Server:*** Apache 2.4
>
> ***Database:*** MySQL v14.14 distribution 5.7.25
>
> ***PHP:*** 7.2
>
> **Redis:** 5.0.4

## Issue

Following the [digitalocean tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-redis) referenced within the [magento devdocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/redis/config-redis.html), I am directed to [another digitalocean tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-redis-on-ubuntu-18-04) in order to properly complete the 'Securing Redis' section.

In order to complete 'Step 5 - Renaming Dangerous Commands', I must modify the magento installation to ensure that magento uses my alternative names, rather than the default command names.

## Steps taken

There is no 'out-of-the-box' method for doing this and so I am unsure how to proceed.

Presumably, I could either create a module to extend Magento's caching features, or, I could use an external software or script to execute the Redis commands alongside the functional elements of the default Magento commands.

Ideally, I would like to store the command names as environment variables, then have a custom module within magento retrieve the command names and override those used by default.

I originally raised this as an [issue on Magento's github](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/22519), though the dev team does not consider this security flaw an issue and so they told me to raise it as a [feature request on their 'community features' github project page](https://github.com/magento/community-features/issues/163).